# Storing Backups on Google Cloud (free/lowcost how ?)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have been using a different 3rd party server provider for years, my backups are done nightly, sites are zipped and posted to AWS bucket.

I recently moved to Google Cloud and I see my egree traffic is shooting through the roof each night and costing a fortune.

So now I need a new solution, How do folks manage to backup servers on Google Compute that doest cost a fortune.

Comment: A common method to reduce the size of your backups is by reducing the frequency of your full backups and introducing *incremental backups.* Proper configuration management (of both server configuration and application deployment and configuration) can *remove the need for full server backups* and will *limit your backup to only the application data.*

Comment: It is currently only essential data, it has to be taken every day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To backup you data at Google Cloud** you can use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) instead of copying backup data to AWS bucket.

Have a look at the documentation [Storage classes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes) to find more details:

> [Nearline Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#nearline) is a low-cost, highly durable storage service
> for storing infrequently accessed data. Nearline Storage is a better
> choice than Standard Storage in scenarios where slightly lower
> availability, a 30-day minimum storage duration, and costs for data
> access are acceptable trade-offs for lowered at-rest storage costs.

and

> [Coldline Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#coldline) is a very-low-cost, highly durable storage
> service for storing infrequently accessed data. Coldline Storage is a
> better choice than Standard Storage or Nearline Storage in scenarios
> where slightly lower availability, a 90-day minimum storage duration,
> and higher costs for data access are acceptable trade-offs for lowered
> at-rest storage costs.

and

> [Archive Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#archive) is the lowest-cost, highly durable storage
> service for data archiving, online backup, and disaster recovery.
> Unlike the "coldest" storage services offered by other Cloud
> providers, your data is available within milliseconds, not hours or
> days.
>
> Unlike other Cloud Storage storage classes, Archive Storage has no
> availability SLA, though the typical availability is comparable to
> Nearline Storage and Coldline Storage. Archive Storage also has higher
> costs for data access and operations, as well as a 365-day minimum
> storage duration. Archive Storage is the best choice for data that you
> plan to access less than once a year.

After that, have a look at the documentation [Object Lifecycle Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle):

> To support common use cases like setting a Time to Live (TTL) for
> objects, retaining noncurrent versions of objects, or **"downgrading"
> storage classes of objects to help manage costs**, Cloud Storage
> offers the Object Lifecycle Management feature.

and at the section [**`SetStorageClass`** cost advantages](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#setstorageclass-cost):

> Unlike [changing an object's storage class manually](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/changing-storage-classes), Object
> Lifecycle Management does not rewrite an object when it changes the
> object's storage class. This gives Object Lifecycle Management certain
> pricing advantages:
>
> - There are **no** [retrieval fees or early deletion fees](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#archival-pricing) associated with the storage class change, even when the object is
>   originally set to Nearline Storage or Coldline Storage.
> - The object's time spent set at the original storage class counts towards any minimum storage duration that applies for the new storage
>   class.

**To estimate cost of usage** you can use [GCP Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator).

Comment: It’s doesn’t fix the issue of egress traffic out of my VM which is what causes the big bills

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation [All networking pricing](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing) section [VM-to-Google Cloud service](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing#egress-to%20service): "For Cloud Storage network pricing, see [Cloud Storage pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-pricing)" and if you follow the link you'll find that "Data moves within the same location." are free of charge.

Comment: As an alternative solution, you can create [snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots) of your VM instances on a schedule.

Comment: In addition, you can enable [VPC Flow Logs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-flow-logs) to collect and analyze detailed information about your networking.

Comment: I didn’t know data transfers were free within the same region, thank you !

Comment: Thank you for confirmation.